# I'm new to triggers concept, can someone help me!

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a question on apex triggers. Trigger.new is the list of new records that can be inserted and trigger.old is the list of old records or the existing records in the database. If we are doing an after update trigger on an account object, why do we loop through trigger.new instead of trigger.old????

Answer (score 0):

`Trigger.new` will hold values which are newly changed but `Trigger.old` will hold values from database.

Lets say from UI you changed account-fieldA from '20' to '30' .So if you loop on `Trigger.old` and if you are expecting some logic which checks if `fieldA` > `30` then run some function it would fail. Because `Trigger.old` will hold value from DB and as the transaction is not committed yet, the value `30` is not yet committed to DB.

So we use trigger.new to loop in expecting all the values which are changed from UI will be available there. And `trigger.old` is used to compare if the value is changed then proceed running the trigger.

Comment: i got u @Nagendra Singh  thanks!!